# Is there any evidence to suggest a shift in ideology or attitudes towards children and childhood in the welfare issue of poverty?

Tags: poverty

I am preparing for my exam at University on Social Policy, one of the questions is Is there any evidence to suggest a shift in ideology or attitudes towards children and childhood in the issue of poverty?

I get that ideologies are 'The Beveridge Report', and the minimalist approach and the con-lib approach etc. just struggling to answer how the ideologies have shifted?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if this is ontopic here (sounds more like Sociology?), but it's a rare pleasure to see a homework question where the poster **did their own work** before asking. +1

Comment: Haha thank you, I've done everything for my prep just this question is so difficult!!